# How to make device vibrate programmatically in BB10

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am very new to blackberry 10 development, i wanted to vibrate the bbdevice programmatically
for some specific duration. How can we do that?
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: by seaching through internet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`VibrationController`](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__device__vibrationcontroller.html) class.